# How to delete a file/folder in a SDCARD under Android Platform?

Tags: android, file, directory, delete-file, android-file

I want to know how to delete a file/folder in SD Card. I tried the code below:

```
File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String fileName = folder.getPath() + "/LOST.DIR/ppt52.ppt";
File myFile = new File(fileName);
if(myFile.exists()) {
    myFile.delete();
}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the folder you are trying to access is Protected. So try to change the access mode before accessing it.

Or you are missing the following permission,

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```