# How to attach image to MMS from Drawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to attach image from resource/drawable folder to MMS.Is it possible to attach image from drawable folder to MMS.if yes then please provide me some code here.I tried a lot and also found a lot here on So as well as on Google but still not able to get the right solution yet.Please some one help me for my this issue.Thanks in Advance.My code is as:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",
                getResources().getText(R.string.Message));

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath(), "koala.jpg");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this in following steps

First get the bitmap of image  from your [drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Then save that bitmap to [SDcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263375/android-saving-created-bitmap-to-directory-on-sd-card)

Then give that sdCard file path to you `sendIntent`

Comment: but i dont want to store that image in SD Card.I just want to attach image to MMS directly from drawable.is it possible to attach image from drawable folder?

Comment: I this it is not possible for android current implementation. may be in future :)

Comment: if i want to attach image from URL MMS then What should i have to do?

Comment: well i am attaching image from drawable folder to email successfully but why its not possible to MMS?Any Specific Reason behind that?

Comment: If you want to attach a image from url then first download that image on sdCard then send the file path. here is some help how to download the image from URL :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328898/load-image-from-url-in-android-only-if-small

Comment: have you tried like this `Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.sample_1);`

Comment: Then you need to implement the above solution.

Comment: you mean to say i have to Store image in SD Card?

Comment: No, just temporary copy the image from your `drawable` folder to `SdCard` and after sending the MMS you can delete that image.

Comment: do you know how to delete file from SD Card after MMS set Successfully.I tried it with filepath.delete but this code delete file before sending file to Receiver.Any suggestion regarding this problem?

Comment: You have no strict need of deleting file just overwrite the existing file when sending a new MMS and in this way you always have one file on sdcard, and that is not a big deal :)

Comment: but i dont want to saw this file to User in SD card.

Comment: there are more than 20 file i am storing in SD card that's why i have to delete each file.please help me for this.

Comment: here is the help to implement the delete operation :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922714/how-to-delete-a-file-folder-in-a-sdcard-under-android-platform

Comment: i store that image to SD Card it works perfectly on all devices except galaxy S3.i cannot able attach file from the SD card to MMS   because there is no SD card in Galaxy S3 for that what should i have to do?Help me for this.hanks in Advance

Comment: You can use internal memory to store the images.

Comment: but i don't know how to store that audio file to internal memory of galaxy S3.Can you please help me for this?

Comment: get help from here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017292/android-create-file-on-internal-storage

Comment: is there any permission i have to give to access the file from the internal Memory?

Comment: this is for writing external storage :-`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21453/discussion-between-ali-imran-and-romil)

Comment: attach audio file to MMS Successfully to all devices Except Samsung galaxy S2,Naxus etc.How to solve this problem?