# How do I text an android drawable?

Tags: java, android, sms

I am currently sending a message with a drawable using this code...

```
    global.fileUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.flipable.flipable/drawable/fliptest");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/png");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,global.fileUri);
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The problem with this is that drawable type (.png) is not getting picked up.  So, if I send over email, it works, and it sends as an extentionless file. but over SMS, it doesn't work because the extension is missing.

How do I send a drawable file over SMS?  Is there a simple way to rename the file to send, so that SMS recognizes it?  Something like...

```
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.STREAM_NAME, "FILE_NAME.PNG");
```

Comment: Rather MMS, than SMS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818138/how-to-attach-image-to-mms-from-drawable-in-android

Comment: The real goal is to send a preloaded .png.  I dont want to have to prompt the user if I dont have to.  Perhaps I can store it as an asset?

Comment: SMS is text only.  SMS does not send images.  When you look like you get an image texted to you, they're really sending an MMS

Comment: I must be sending an MMS then.  Thats my bad.  I didnt realize the distinction.  I used the same method to send a uri I got from a file open intent.